# iteration through a loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

Lets assume n=20

so after every 6 iterations I will do some processing

```
     int i=0        
     for (t=6;t<20;t=t+6){
       while(i<=t){
          will do some processing


          i++;

        }

   }
```

In the above code it will terminate when t=18, but I want to continue until 20.
How to do that ?

Comment: but why? you are increasing the t variable 6 units... the last condition that satisfies the t<20 is when t =18.....

Comment: Except if you're incrementing by 6 every time, you will never reach 20.

Comment: maybe you want to increment by 1, but in your while loop check that `t % 6 == 0` ?

Comment: @ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa
actually the value of 20 is result obtained from some other calculation.
it could be any value  based on the calculation
For example the resultant value of n could be 31 and i need to go till 31 after every 6 iteration

Comment: @AtimorapParomita What are your intentions with `t=t+6` and `while(i<=t)`. Could you elaborate on the question, please?

Answer (score 2):

You are increasing the t variable 6 units... the last condition that satisfies the `t<20` is when `t = 18`.

instead of doing `t+=6` do a normal `t++` and play with the modulo `%6`

example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 20;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        //TODDY
        insert your while in here depending on when that must be executed
        if (i % 6 == 0) {
            System.out.println("am on a 6 modulo step..." + i);
        } else {
            System.out.println("foo@" + i);
        }

    }
    System.out.println("done");
}
```

Comment: n = 20 is not used

Comment: Are you not eating up the `while` part of the question?

Comment: @nullpointer yes... now I updated... OP never told anything whether the while has something to do with the modulo6 operation... so is just a ToDo for him

Comment: the code does not handle when it is on the last iteration. Yes, it seems obvious but given the fact that it's specifically handling every 6th iteration and that the OP specifically requested for one last iteration handling, i believe it is worth it. My answer does include that.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour is correct only.. Still if you want to perform any operation, do it after the condition is met, try below snippet:

```
int i = 0, n = 20;
    do{
        i += 6;
        System.out.println(i);
    } while (i < n);
System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: how to accept ? I voted for the answer
is there any other way to accept it ?

Comment: well in your version it will print upto 23

public static void main(String args[]){
        int t = 0, n = 20, i=0;
    do{
        t += 6;
        while(i<t){
        System.out.println(i);
        i++;
        }
    } while (t < n);
//System.out.println(i);
        
    }

Comment: if n==0 it will do anyway one execution

Comment: I understood, what you are looking for... try this:

public static void main(String args[]) {
  int t = 0, n = 20, i = 0;
  do {
   t += 6;
   System.out.println("---------------");
   while (i < t && i < n) {

    System.out.println("\t" + i);
    i++;
   }
  } while (t < n); // System.out.println(i); }

 }

Comment: Just add `i < n` to while(i<t) condition... i.e., while (i < t && i < n)

Answer (score 1):

your code is not doing something every 6th iteration, but instead you are doing (n - n%6) times. your "will do some processing" is inside the while. If you add a print (or debug) there you will notice it; on the n=20 example the while will be executed 18 times; it will do something 18 times.

if you want to execute every 6th iterations, and include one extra for the cases that are not exactly divisible by 6, then you could do:

```
if (n == 0) {
    return;
}

int number_iterations = n/6 + (n%6!=0 ? 1:0);

for (int i=0; i<number_iterations; i++) {
    // do something
}
```

That covers what you requested; if not, pls edit question to be more clear on your exact needs.